# Помогите найти баг Opencart Jquerry

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, opencart

```
 <?php if ($quote['code'] == $code || !$code) { ?>
                                <?php $code = $quote['code']; ?>
                                <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>"
                                       />
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>"
                                />
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php echo $quote['title']; ?> - <?php echo $quote['text']; ?>
                            <?php if (isset($quote['description'])) { ?>
                                <br/><small><?php echo $quote['description']; ?></small>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php } ?>

        <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger"><?php echo $shipping_method['error']; ?></div>
        <?php } ?>

    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>

<div class="save_shipping_method active">Далее</div>

<p style="display: none">
    <textarea name="comment" rows="8" class="form-control"><?php echo $comment; ?></textarea>
</p>
<div class="buttons" style="display: none">
    <div class="pull-right" style="display: none">
        <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_continue; ?>" id="button-shipping-method"
               data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(()=> {

     
        $('#shipping_method input').change((e) => {
            if(e.target.value === 'cdek.tariff_10_MRG' && e.target.checked) {

                $('#selectCdekPvz').removeClass('disabled')
                
                if(!$('.cdek_selectedPvzInfo').text().length) {
                    $('.save_shipping_method').addClass('disabled') // disabled
                }else {
                    $('.save_shipping_method').addClass('active')
                }

            }else {
                $('#selectCdekPvz').addClass('disabled')
            }
        })

        const onClickCdek = $('#selectCdekPvz.disabled').attr('onclick');
        $('#selectCdekPvz.disabled').removeAttr('onclick')
        $('#selectCdekPvz').click((e) => {
            if(!document.getElementById('selectCdekPvz').classList.contains('disabled')){
                eval(onClickCdek);
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

В общем, на сайте https://posezony.ru/ при оформлении заказа, когда выбираешь доставку СДЭК, но не выбираешь пункт выдачи блокируется кнопка далее, так и должно быть. Но при этом, если выбирается доставка самовывозом кнопка не разблокируется, как это можно решить?

Comment: Сами как думаете? За вас здесь это делать вряд ли будут если вы сами не проявляете телодвижения для решения проблемы.

Comment: А как понять в js где вы проверяете самовывоз да/нет ? Думаю у вас каждое действие не удовлетворяет требованию `e.target.value === 'cdek.tariff_10_MRG' && e.target.checked` и всегда на кнопку добавляется `disabled`